# "Make a success of"

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "make a success of" to imply that something succeeds?

For example:

> There are many famous novelists who made a complete success of their first novel.

I want to say that the novelists succeeded in their first novel.

Comment: Theresa May tells Cabinet, ‘Brexit means Brexit – and ***we’ll make it a success’***.

Comment: If I made a success of my first novel, the implication would probably be that I wrote it well (in the opinion of myself and/or literary critics) or that I successfully completed the *writing* (I didn't fail to work on it regularly, and I made sure I had a publisher lined up, etc.). If my first novel succeeded that would normally just mean it sold well.

Answer (score 2):

"... whose first novel was a complete success" sounds better.  It is possible to "make [someone/something] a success", as in, "Her first novel made her a success almost overnight.", but "make a success of" doesn't sound right.

Ironically, you can "make a *mess* of" something.  But not a success of it.